# Как авторизоваться в Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Установил Tomcat на VPS с Ubuntu 16.04, все работает, но авторизоваться никак не получается. На данный момент в файле `tomcat-users.xml` вот такие настройки:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-gui"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

Захожу под пользователем `manager`, но не получается. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? В файлах manager и host-manager настроено все настроено, иначе вылезала бы другая ошибка. Расположение tomcat-users: `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

Содержимое tomcat.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: этого достаточно.. нужно быть уверенным, что томми читает именно эти настройки

Comment: Помимо того, что добавили пользователей с ролями, у `manager` нужно разрешить доступ не с локолхоста, [подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462403/6752984) . Закомментируйте строки как указано по ссылке в файле `CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml`

Comment: Возможно томкат действительно не видит этот файл, но как это можно проверить? Добавил содержимое tomcat.service в вопросе. Расположение `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

Comment: А какая именно ошибка вылезает у вас?

Comment: Ошибки не появляется, просто табличка "Необходима авторизация" появляется заново после любого ввода. Ошибка 401 на странице /manager/html появляется только если закрыть окно авторизации